# How to search sequence of Date Ranges in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

When trying to check date ranges it does not return values. Here `st_date` and `end_date` for `usr_id = 1` is sequence so it should return only `usr_id = 1` values and should not return `usr_id = 3` since it is not sequence . If the date range is not in sequence, it should not return any value.

```
    CREATE TABLE #temp(st_date DATE,end_date DATE,usr_id INT)
INSERT  #temp 
VALUES ('2007-03-01  ','2015-01-31  ',1),
  ('2015-02-01  ','2017-04-01  ',1),
  ('2007-03-01  ','2014-01-31  ',2),
  ('2007-03-01  ','2015-01-31  ',3),
  ('2015-03-02  ','2017-04-01  ',3)
DECLARE @st_dt DATE = '2009-02-01 00:00:00',@end_dt DATE = '2017-01-01 00:00:00'

SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE  @st_dt BETWEEN st_date AND end_date
AND @end_dt BETWEEN st_date AND end_date

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The `#temp` thing looks like SQL Server?

Comment: i dont understand what you wanna do

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM #temp t
    INNER JOIN #temp t2 ON t.usr_id = t2.usr_id AND t.end_date = DATEADD(dd, -1, t2.st_date)
WHERE   @st_dt BETWEEN t.st_date AND t.end_date
    AND @end_dt BETWEEN t2.st_date AND t2.end_date
```